# How to calculate and display a specific date?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, date

I'm writing up an online contract for an e-commerce/rental site and need to display the date of the first payment.

The first payment is due the first occurrence of the 1st or the 15th of the month, beginning 30 days from the date of the contract. So if the contract was filled out on January 10th, the first payment would be due on February 15th.

I'm lost on how to make this happen with JS, so your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**

So let's say I'm using this code as recommended below:

```
function calc() {
    var invoiceDate = moment(document.getElementById("contractDate").value, ["M-D-YYYY"]).add(30, 'days');

    while (invoiceDate.date() != 1 && invoiceDate.date() != 15) {
        invoiceDate = invoiceDate.add(1, 'days')
    }
    document.getElementById("invoiceDate").innerHTML = invoiceDate.format("MMMM Do, YYYY");
}

calc()



<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="contractDate" onchange="calc()" value="12-18-2014">
<div id="invoiceDate"></div>
```

How would I set it to automatically update to the current date instead of requiring a text form to fill out? Getting rid of the text input would be best to keep people from fudging the contract. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just some simple maths and [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: I would take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). That will make your life infinitely easier with regards to manipulating the date in javascript.

Comment: If the date was `Jan 15`, would it still be `Feb 15`? or do you jump to `Mar 1`? (Does it have to be +30 but cannot fall on 30 I guess is the question)

Comment: @BradChristie In that case, the first payment date would be February 15th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using pure javascript in reasonably straightforward manner

```js
function calc(){
  var contractDate = new Date(document.getElementById("contractDate").value)
  console.log('contractDate',contractDate);

  var invoiceDate = new Date(contractDate);
  invoiceDate.setDate(invoiceDate.getDate() + 30)

  while( invoiceDate.getDate() != 1 && invoiceDate.getDate() != 15){
    invoiceDate.setDate(invoiceDate.getDate() + 1)
  }
  document.getElementById("invoiceDate").innerHTML = invoiceDate;
}

calc()
```

```html
<input type="text" id="contractDate" onchange="calc()" value="2014-01-10">
<div id="invoiceDate"></div>
```

However, as a comment said, dealing with dates is far more complex than it first appears, use something like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

```js
function calc(){
  var invoiceDate = moment(document.getElementById("contractDate").value,["YYYY-MM-DD"]).add(30,'days');
   
  while( invoiceDate.date() != 1 && invoiceDate.date() != 15){
    invoiceDate = invoiceDate.add(1,'days')
  }
  document.getElementById("invoiceDate").innerHTML = invoiceDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
}

calc()
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="contractDate" onchange="calc()" value="2014-01-10">
<div id="invoiceDate"></div>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect! Is there any way to auto-update the date as set in the input field?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my bid:

```js
// http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js

function getNextBillingDate(d){
    var m = new moment(d);
    m = m.add(1, 'month');
    if (m.date() > 15){
        m = m.add('1', 'month').date(1);
    } else if (m.date() > 1) {
        m = m.date(15);
    }
    return m.toDate();
}

var t = document.getElementById('t');
function test(input,expected){
    var actual = getNextBillingDate(input);
    
    var im = new moment(input),
        em = new moment(expected),
        am = new moment(actual);
    
    t.innerHTML += im.format('L') + ' => ' + am.format('L');
    t.innerHTML += ' (' + (em.isSame(am) ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL') + ')' + '\r\n';
}
test(new Date('Jan 10, 2016'), new Date('Feb 15, 2016'));
test(new Date('Jan 15, 2016'), new Date('Feb 15, 2016'));
test(new Date('Jan 16, 2016'), new Date('Mar 1, 2016'));
test(new Date('Mar 1, 2016'), new Date('Apr 1, 2016'));





// Only scroll down if you care about the input field in the demo
$('#d').val(moment().format('L'));
$('#b').on('click', function(e){
  try {
    var d = new moment(getNextBillingDate(new Date($('#d').val())));
    $('#r').text(d.format('L'));
  } catch(ex) {
    $('#r').text('Error');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="d" /><button id="b">Convert</button><span id="r"></span>

<pre id="t">Unit Tests:
</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at a framework called 
[MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

What you would do is the following:

```
moment(beginning date here, format here).add(30, 'days')
```

so in your case this would result in:

```
moment("15-01-2014", ["DD-MM-YYYY"]).add(30, 'days')
```

this is in DayDay-MonthMonth-YearYearYearYear notation, but change it to your desire.
after this line of code you have a moment object.
In my case, i retreive the date from it using the following method:

```
getDateFromMoment(moment){
    var currentDay = moment.date();
      if(currentDay < 10){
          currentDay = '0' + moment.date();
      }
      var currentMonth = moment.month() + 1;
      if(currentMonth < 10){
          currentMonth = '0' + (moment.month() + 1);
      }
      var currentYear = moment.year();
      return currentDay + "-" + currentMonth + "-" + currentYear;
}
```

this will return a string form date, e.g. "15-02-2014".
The framework itself might need a little "getting used to", but promise me.. it's worth your while

Advantages of this framework:

1. Easy to learn
2. Will calculate correctly through yearchanges, february inconsistencies, years with 53 or 52 weeks, anything that problems with dates can throw at you, MomentJS has got you covered!
3. You can customize this into your application, change locale, format, you can throw in more than just a string date object, but also a JavaScript object, and lots and lots more.

Hope I helped you ;)

Comment: You're using momentjs, but turning this into string manupilation.... Ugh! `</disappointed>`

Comment: Also, [I tried this](http://jsfiddle.net/q3vxcqje/) and it gives the wrong result.

Comment: But this returned the right result, for Januari has only 30 days, therefore it returns 14-02 :| Also i see why string manipulation is bad